# Migration for association with same Table multiple time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

So I want to reference 2 Users in my Item model by using class_name option. My question is how do I create a migration for this?

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :founder, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :loser, class_name: "User"

end
```

My first thought is:

```
  def change
    add_reference :items, :user, index: true
    add_reference :items, :user, index: true
  end
```

However, it's obviously a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
change_table :items do |t|
  t.add_reference :founder
  t.add_reference :loser
end
```

Comment: does the `index:true` part matters? I got it when I use the migration generator, but not quite sure what it does or when I should include it.

Comment: @doog if I remember correctly, `add_reference` adds index by default.